# Why won't Tekken 3 start?

Tags: games

I want to play Tekken 3 but it doesn't start on Ubuntu. What should I do?

Comment: Please be more specific. I assume Tekken 3 is a PS1 disc, do you have an emulator installed, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Tekken 3 is a game developed for the Sony PS1 game console. It would not play directly on your ubuntu system. You have to first install a playstation emulator for the ubuntu software centre. Once that is done, consult the software's manual on lading and playing the game.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have Tekken 3 for playstation? Use software center to install Playstation emulator.